# Display multiple instances of the same div

Tags: jquery, html, multiple-instances

I have a listing of names that I want to be able to add data to using a form.

e.g.,
John Doe
Sally Smith
Jennifer Jackson

I would like to be able to display the form under the selected name using jquery and a form in a div. So, if the user clicks on Sally Smith, the form div displays below her name.

e.g.,
John Doe
Sally Smith
    `FORM DIV HERE`
Jennifer Jackson

I know how to show/hide a div, but I do not know how I can reproduce the same div multiple times. Each div contains the same information, but it needs to be displayed under the clicked name. It would be nice if I could just create the div once and change an identifier for the div to be the same as the person's name. (i.e., `class="sally-smith-form"`)

Do I need to create the form div for each name in the listing or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/). You can copy the element, and then append after another element:

```
$('#place_to_insert').after($('.sally-form-form:first').clone());
```